# Facebook Canvas App: This method is only accessible to Games

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I get the following error when trying to access a user's invitable friends list through a Facebook Canvas App:

"error":{"message":"(#15) This method is only accessible to Games."

I have searched all over the web and the consensus to get past this error is that your app has to be :

- classified as a 'Game' within your app's settings
- have a Canvas presence - which means enabling the Canvas platform within your app's settings

So my Facebook app was already set as a Canvas app. I did this under 'Settings' and just added my Secure Canvas URL.

Next I had to classify my app as a 'game'. OK, less clear, but I changed the Category of my app to 'Game' under 'App Details' and I also set a 'Sub Category' for my game.

But the error persists. I am still getting: "error":{"message":"(#15) This method is only accessible to Games."

The call that generates this error is just the stock standard invitable friends javascript that I got from the Facebook website:

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
  "/me/invitable_friends",
  function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
      /* handle the result */
    }
  }
);
```

Please help!

Comment: First of all make sure that you are actually using the correct app id when initializing the JS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

this works perfectly with yours conf like the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/canvas-tutorial):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      FB.init({
        appId: appId ,
        frictionlessRequests: true,
        status: true,
        version: 'v2.4'
      });

      FB.AppEvents.activateApp();
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', onAuthResponseChange);
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', onStatusChange);
    });


    function onStatusChange(response) {
      if( response.status != 'connected' ) {
        login(loginCallback);
      } else {
        getMe(function(){
          getPermissions(function(){
            if(hasPermission('user_friends')) {
              getFriends(function(){
                getInvitablefriends();   
              });
            } else {
              console.log("without permissions")
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }

    function getInvitableFriends(callback) {
      FB.api('/me/invitable_friends', {fields: 'id,name,first_name,picture.width(120).height(120)'}, function(response){
        if( !response.error ) {
          console.log(response.data);
          callback();
        } else {
          console.error('/me/invitable_friends', response);
        }
      });
    }
```